# neovim: How to exit "raw" "raw" [readonly] 5L, 190C

Tags: neovim

I've recently downloaded nvim and have been using it for a few weeks with no problems.

Now I'm getting this every time I start nvim:
`"raw" "raw" [readonly] 5L, 190C`

I can't figure out how this happened or how to revert back to edit mode.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Connor

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you describe how you start nvim? I wonder if you might have better luck opening an issue on their GitHub

Comment: Looks like it's opening a file named `raw`, with 5 lines and 190 characters... Does it get fixed if you start NeoVim with `nvim -u NONE` or `nvim -i NONE` or `nvim --clean`?